# Script startup is slow when started with "Run with Powershell"

Tags: powershell

When I start a script with "Run with Powershell" its starting slow.
First it is searching for avaiable modules and after this its asking for a Execution Policy Change. Is there a way to suspend them?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Which version of Powershell are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with version 3, Powershell does module autoloading, which you can disable by adding this line to your Powershell script (or profile):

```
$PSModuleAutoloadingPreference = “none”
```

Be careful, though, as this means that any cmdlet/function that's not part of the default modules Powershell loads at startup will not be available.
As an indication, I launched `(get-command).count` both with and without that line:
Module autoloading on: 1753
Module autoloading off: 213

If you need to load more modules, you can simply add `Import-module` instructions in your script.

As for the execution policy, you can also force it when launching powershell:

```
powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted <path to your script>
```

As was mentioned earlier, be careful with this parameter, as it will enable launching any Powershell script on your system. As long as you're in control of what scripts you're launching, there's nothing to be worried about.

Answer (score 0):

Sure but [understand the consequences](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849812.aspx)

Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted –Forc

Comment: Less [technical breakdown](http://jeffwouters.nl/index.php/2011/11/powershell-and-the-exectution-policies-explained/)

Comment: This is verging on a [link-only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Maybe summarize the consequences in your answer

Comment: I know, that i can change the Execution Policy. By GPo the setting is RemoteSigned.
But why is powershell asking me to change it when i run a script?